# Compatibility with FAT32 using 1024 sector size

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, sd-card, fat32, embedded

On an embedded system, we are using FAT32 with 512 sector size on SDCard.

We will be writing files of 800k and need to do this quickly.

Our filesystem code writes in blocks of 512 to the SDCard because this is the sector size.

Our profiling shows better performance if we can increase the byte count when writing to the SDCard.  For example, we will get better performance by writing blocks of 1024 bytes.

One of our preferences is to be able to read the SDCard on the PC.

Questions:

1. Can the PC (Windows 7) read FAT32 SDCards with 1024 sector size?
2. Can the SDCard be formatted (partitioned) on the PC (Windows 7) for
   1024 byte sector size?

Comment: There is nothing about FAT32 standard that would prevent this.

Comment: The FAT32 specification would allow this, but most implementations of FAT32 use only the old standard of 512 bytes.  More requires support for the "Advanced Format" specification.  SD cards max out at 2GB, the max of FAT16 w/ signed numbers, which would not be a necessary max/limit if they accepted non-standard code (using unsigned numbers would allow 4GB).  Instead, the SD association released newer specifications, the SDHC standard and later the SDXC standard, which permitted higher limits.  If you could format an SD card different, it wouldn't be fully compatible with all SD devices.

Comment: @TOOGAM: We are using 64GB SDXC cards.

Comment: [Wikipedia's article on Secure Digital: SDXC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDXC) : "SDXC cards utilize the exFAT file system", by Windows Vista SP1+, OSX 10.6.5+, XP and Server 2003 w/ updates, generally not BSD/etc (unless extra software is added).  [MS KB 140365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/140365) lists sector sizes for other filesystem types, but for exFAT it lists "cluster sizes" of 4KB and larger.  I also found some info about different cluster sizes with FAT32.  Do you really mean "cluster" size?

Comment: Since exFAT is proprietary, we have used the PC to repartition the SDXC card to use FAT32.  I'm most likely sure that cluster and sector size are the same.